# Pandas: How to create a new column that adds selected columns across rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns, subtraction

I would like to create a new column called "Excess Return" that is =('SPX TR'-'3M Govt'), and I want to place it to the right of the '3M Govt' column. How do I do that?

Please call the following table "df"

```
      Date      SPX TR  3M Govt  Div Yield  Real Dividends
```

0      1940-01-31   12.2531   0.0200   0.044580       10.343730

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Val_Diff'] = dfB['SPX TR'] - dfB['3M Govt']
```

after this sort your columns

```
df = df[['SPX TR', '3M Govt', 'Val_Diff', 'Div Yield', 'Real Dividends']]
```